# Hide zero XAxis date value

Tags: date, charts, hide, zero

I have a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart three values and assiciated with the same date (15.07.15). Now it looks like at [the picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58743910/20121899.png).
Is there any way to hide "zero" "30.12.1899" date?

Answer (score 0):

```
chart1.ChartAreas[index].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: thank you, but i don't require extra clarification. are you sure that this does not provide the answer, have you tried the solution, in order to justify marking the answer for deletion?

Answer (score 0):

> .LabelStyle.Enabled = false;

It hides all axis lables.
To hide a "zero" just set .AxisX.Minimum to something like 1e-12;